# Yii2 How to list out dropdownlist option values from database without duplicate values?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, query-builder

For categories dropdowList i am generating values from database, in that main_cat column has electronics value two times, in the dropdown also its repeating two times, how display it only once?

```
+--------+-------------+---------+
| cat_id | main_cat    | sub_cat |
+--------+-------------+---------+
| 1      | Electronics | Phones  |
+--------+-------------+---------+
| 2      | Electronics | TVs     |
+--------+-------------+---------+
| 3      | Furniture   | Sofa    |
+--------+-------------+---------+
```

I tried below code but it is repeating the electronics in the dropdown `distinct()` not working.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'ad_cat_id',
            'template' => '<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Category</label><div class="col-sm-9">{input}{error}</div>',
 ])->dropDownList(
         ArrayHelper::map(Categories::find()->distinct()->all(), 'cat_id', 'main_cat'),
           [
           prompt' => 'Please select main category',

 ]) ?>
```

**How to select main_cat column without repeating same values?**

Comment: You map this to `cat_id` - in this case what `id` should be chosen - 1 or 2?

Comment: You mean that drodpdown list should render something like `<option value="1,2">Electronics</option>`?

Comment: no like <option value="1">Electronics</option>
           <option value="3">Furniture</option>

Comment: Are you sure? It looks like `cat_id` is the ID of `sub_cat` (not `main_cat`).

Comment: @Bizley Thanks!! got it there is a small problem, i have to change the database structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as

```
Categories::find()->groupBy('main_cat')->all();
```

Comment: thanks man!! it worked, i am gonna develop my final project in yii2 so i need some help do you mind if i add you in skype or facebook?